# Should I create dummy object to be able to synchronize on properties that may be null?

Tags: java, multithreading

Imagine you have a class that represents lazy loaded image. This means it only loads the image if needed and then caches it:

```
public class LazyImage {
  //Path souldn't ever change
  public final File path;
  //This will be filled when the image is loaded
  private Image image = null;
  public LazyImage(File path) {
    //I ommited some safety checks chere, like null check and existence check.
    this.path = path;
  }

  public Image getImage() {
    if(image!=null)
      return image;
    try {
      image = ImageIO.read(path);
    }
    catch(IOException e) {
      //Here, the class should remember that there was a problem getting the image
      // and probably not try again, based on the exception type
    }
  }
}
```

If you'd use such class in more complex application, you'd soon find out you need to make it thread safe, so that there aren't multiple threads invoking `image = ImageIO.read(path);` at the same time. In this particular case, you want to synchronize like this:

```
  public final String imageMutex = "Prevents the image property from being modified multiple times.";
  public Image getImage() {
    if(image!=null)
      return image;
    //This only executes if the image was nullptr right now
    synchronized(imageMutex) {
      //If was blocked, check for the null once again
      //most likely will not be null any more
      if(image==null) {
        File file = new File(path);
        try {
          image = ImageIO.read(file);
        }
        catch(IOException e) {
          image=null;
          image_failed = true;
        }
      }
    }
    return image;
  }
```

I am actually not entirely sure how safe the non-synchronized `if` at the beginning of the method is. But this question is about the `imageMutex` variable. I can't synchronize on `image` because it's null at the beginning. I also don't want to synchronize on the `getImage` method, because it would block the threads even when they are just reading the image.

So how do programmers synchronize on *variable*, rather then specific object or method?

Comment: Why not synchronize on `this`?

Comment: @RealSkeptic What if there were 2 variables to synchronize over? Variable A would then block variable B.

Comment: If you have two independent state variables, yes, of course. But when you only have one state variable, or the state variables are always manipulated together, then `this` is a good option. Is it likely that your `LazyImage` will have such complicated state?

Comment: @RealSkeptic `LazyImage` was just general picture of the problem. The real class also caches resized images and clears images that will be no longer used... Synchronizing on this would make different operations block each other. In the question, I was looking for some general purpose solution. In simple classes you can surelly synchronize on `this`, but I wouldn't recommend it. If other class is using your class as property and *also* synchronizes on it, you may have a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, pretty much how you've done it!

Most of the time, the mutex (often aka "guard" in this type of context) is just `Object imageLock = new Object ()`, but otherwise you've got it right.

Your `image` field needs to be volatile, though, for this scheme -- called a [double checked lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) -- to work.

Comment: According to [this site](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_volatile.shtml), volatile variable blocks every time it's accessed. Is that true?

Comment: I think it's important to stress why using a literal string as a lock is a bad idea: because of interning, it will be the same object shared by all `LazyImage` objects.

Comment: Yes, what @RealSkeptic said. :)